# How to move a sprite to touch point

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

Hi Raj Thanks for quick response actually what my problem was i have to move a sprite to touch point where ever i touched and also i want to move that sprite along x axis only, for that i use the following code

```
- (void)ccTouchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{       
    for( UITouch *touch in touches ) {

    location = [touch locationInView: [touch view]];

    location = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL: location];

    for(b2Body *b=world->GetBodyList();b;b=b->GetNext()){

    if(b->GetUserData()!=NULL) {`

    CCSprite *myActor =(CCSprite *)b->GetUserData();

    b2Vec2 locationWorld = b2Vec2(location.x/PTM_RATIO, location.y/PTM_RATIO);

    b->SetTransform(b2Vec2(locationWorld.x, locationWorld.y),0);


    NSLog(@"x position of baby sprite is %@",  b->GetPosition().x);

    id action = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:0.4 position:CGPointMake( b->GetPosition().x, b->GetPosition().y)];

     [myActor runAction:action];

}}}}
```

with this code am moving my sprite where ever i want but its not restricted to x axis...... So can u please help me regarding this

thanks in advance

Comment: hmm I'm not familiar with box2d

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use this code:

```
- (void) ccTouchEnded:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
```

//coordinates of the point where we are touching

```
CGPoint tocco = [touch locationInView:[touch view]];
CGPoint tocco2 = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:tocco];
```

//action to move the sprite

```
id muovi = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:1 position:tocco2];

[MySprite runAction:muovi];

//if you want turn the sprite left o right
if (tocco2.x < MySprite.position.x) {

    id sx = [CCFlipX actionWithFlipX:NO];

    [MySprite runAction:sx];

}else{

    id dx = [CCFlipX actionWithFlipX:YES];

    [MySprite runAction:dx];

}
```

}